# Can't open chrome in multiple computers using dsh

Tags: shell-script, ubuntu, ssh, chrome

I'm trying to create a script that opens chrome in a specific page, because I'd like to do that in many clients. However, when trying to run it from my server (using `dsh`) or even when trying to execute directly the google-chrome command, this message appears (I've been logged as root when doing this):

> ```
> (google-chrome:5543): Gtk-WARNING **: 12:26:00.566: cannot open display:`
> ```

My .sh script (open_chrome.sh) is the following:

```
#!/bin/sh
google-chrome www.facebook.com --no-sandbox;
```

This is the full command I used to run the script in the clients (All the clients have the script):

```
dsh -a -c ./Scripts/open_chrome.sh
```

This is the command I used when trying to run the google-chrome order directly (which also gives me the same output)

```
dsh -a -c google-chrome www.facebook.com --no-sandbox
```

However, if I log into the root user of one of my clients and try to execute the script, it works.

**Disclaimer:** I'm new in shell scripting and in asking on this page, so I deeply apologize if I've made any dumb mistake posting the question here or in the commands shown here.

Comment: Please add the output of `echo $DISPLAY` to your question.

Comment: The output on the server is `:1.0` (when logged as root)